# Separately selecting and multiplying numpy 2-d elements per mask (without loops)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, mask

I have a numpy 2-d heatmap and two overlapping masks (with different sizes). I want to multiply the elements insides these masks with a unique numpy array per mask. First I remove the overlapping coordinates from one of the masks. Than I want to extract the heatmap elements per mask without using loops.

The reason for this is that in reality I have over 10000 masks from which a variable number is overlapping. In addition, I have 25 heatmaps with a size of 80000*80000. The challenge is to create an alorithm which is fast and not too memory extensive with these numbers.

Example of heatmap:

```
heatmap = array([[236, 235, 225, 226, 215],
   [214, 217, 220, 215, 228],
   [238, 227, 209, 210, 220],
   [251, 224, 225, 220, 229],
   [  0, 226, 231, 233, 240]], dtype=uint64)
```

Boolean masks:

```
bool1=array([[ True,  True,  True, True, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
   [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
   [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

bool2=array([[False, False, False, False, False],
   [False, False, False,  True, False],
   [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
   [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
   [False, False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Remove overlapping coordinates from second mask:

```
bool2[bool1]=False
```

Right now I select the heatmap elements per mask as follows:

```
combined_bool=[bool1,bool2]
multiply_array1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
multiply_array2=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]) #only 6 Trues in bool2 after duplicate cell removal
combined_mult= [multiply_array1,multiply_array2]

for i in range(0,len(combined_bool)):
    mask=combined_bool[i]
    heatmap[mask]=heatmap[mask]*combined_mult[i]

#output
array([[ 236,  470,  675,  904,  215],
   [1070, 1302, 1540, 1720,  228],
   [2142, 2270, 2299, 2520,  220],
   [3263, 3136, 3375,  440,  687],
   [   0,  226,  924, 1165, 1440]], dtype=uint64)
```

How can I do this multiplication per mask without the use of a for-loop?

Comment: How many  overlapping masks are you working with in your actual case?

Comment: This is a variable number, I also have multiple heatmaps.

Comment: I meant typically. Because that would decide `len(combined_bool)` and if that's a small number, it might not be worth the effort to go for vectorization.

Comment: I guess more than half of them, so around 6000 (my script is currently running).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and few other methods -

```
# Concatenate all input multiply_arrays    
combined_mult_arr = np.hstack((multiply_array1,multiply_array2))

# Concatenate all input boolean arrays      
B = np.dstack((bool1,bool2))  

# 3D mask with the uniqueness set
unqmask = (B.argmax(2) == np.arange(B.shape[2])[:,None,None]) & B.any(2)

# Get True indices in each 3D slice. Index into 1D version of heatmap & multiply
R,C = np.where(unqmask.reshape(unqmask.shape[0],-1))
heatmap.ravel()[C] *= combined_mult_arr
```

Now, to verify the code, let's introduce one more input boolean and multiplication array. So, let's have an additional `bool3` same as `bool2` and set (0,4) element as `True`. Accordingly, let's have additional `multiply_array3` as `np.array([10])`. Thus, a sample run with such modifications would look like as shown next.

1) Inputs :

```
In [126]: heatmap
Out[126]: 
array([[ 236,  470,  675,  904, 2150],
       [1070, 1302, 1540, 1720,  228],
       [2142, 2270, 2299, 2520,  220],
       [3263, 3136, 3375,  440,  687],
       [   0,  226,  924, 1165, 1440]])

In [127]: bool1
Out[127]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [128]: bool2
Out[128]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [129]: bool3
Out[129]: 
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [130]: multiply_array1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
     ...: multiply_array2=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
     ...: multiply_array3=np.array([10])
     ...:
```

2) Run the code :

```
In [133]: combined_mult_arr = np.hstack((multiply_array1,\
     ...:                     multiply_array2,multiply_array3))
     ...: B = np.dstack((bool1,bool2,bool3))  
     ...: unqmask = (B.argmax(2) == np.arange(B.shape[2])[:,None,None]) & B.any(2)
     ...: R,C = np.where(unqmask.reshape(unqmask.shape[0],-1))
     ...: heatmap.ravel()[C] *= combined_mult_arr
     ...:
```

3) Check the output :

```
In [136]: heatmap
Out[136]: 
array([[ 236,  470,  675,  904, 2150],
       [1070, 1302, 1540, 1720,  228],
       [2142, 2270, 2299, 2520,  220],
       [3263, 3136, 3375,  440,  687],
       [   0,  226,  924, 1165, 1440]])
```

As can be seen, the only difference in this output when compared against the output with two inputs case is `2150` at `(0,4)` against `215` before. This is because of the third boolean array and third multiplication array with the element `10` and that's responsible for scaling the `(0,4)` element by `10`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will implement it in my script and tell you the difference in calculation time when I am finished!

Comment: Unfortunately the calculation time is slowed down with about 15 seconds. Using 426 masks on 15 heatmaps with the shape 1400*1035

Comment: In addition, I get a memory error that wasn't there before, when I am using a bigger heatmap. This is probably due to the dstack

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren How are you generating the boolean arrays in your actual case? Do you have those as `bool1`, `bool2`.... `bool426`. I think that would be a bad practice to have so many variables in workspace. So, what I meant to show was that you can stack those boolean arrays when you are generating them instead of having them as `bool1`, `bool2`.... `bool426` and then stacking with `dstack`. Or better if you know before-hand the number of boolean arrays you would be stacking, then initialize a 3D boolean array of appropriate size and then set those iteratively.

Comment: I first create an empty mask of the entire heatmap: mask=np.zeros(shape(heatmap),dtype=bool). Than I repeat this mask with the number of boolean masks:   allmasks=np.repeat(mask[:,:,np.newaxis],no_of_masks,2). Then I set the values of non overlapping masks cells to True: allmasks[non_overlap_coords]=1. I work with heatmaps of 10000*10000 cells, so if i have 200 boolean masks the shape of allmasks will be (200,10000,10000). This is why I get the memory error.

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren Yeah, if you are working with such huge arrays and with 200 such masks, then maybe you are better off with your loopy code.

Comment: Hmm thats unfortunate! Thanks anyway!